# How to get the right page count?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript, I want to get the right page count.

if one page the item count is `20`, and the page count is 23, the page should be `2`.

```
var count = 23

var per_page_count = 20
```

If in other language we can use:

```
count / per_page_count + 1
```

to get the page count, but in JavaScript we can not get it.

I also tried use `Math.round`, still not work

```
console.log(Math.round(count/per_page_count))  // there I want to get 2, but get 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
Math.ceil(count/per_page_count)
```

> The Math.ceil() function returns the smallest integer greater than or equal to a given number.

from [Math.ceil document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil).

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to implement some sort of pagination. So I would suggest :

```
Maths.ceil(count/per_page_count)
```